# NullPointerException when trying to use a listener for FAB in a MAP fragment

Tags: android

This is the error message

[image]

This is my code

[image]

Comment: Instead of putting an image, you should paste your code here

Comment: Copy paste your error and code. Don't post screenshots.

Comment: you need to learn basics about layouts and how to inflate that. Just search about those you will get helpful contents

Comment: Sometimes I get sad if I see questions like this. I mean you are too lazy to add formatted code but comment your own question 1 minute after you created it? If u read the android documentation this would be trivial to you..

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to find **fab** in **fab**, **fab1** in **fab1** ...
You need to get those buttons from root view of your Fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carte_reseaux_fragment, container, false);
   fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
   .
   .
   Animation fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
   //Actually FloatingActionButton has own implementation
   fab.setShowAnimation(fab_open);
   return rootView;
}
```

Comment: thank you , it work for fab,fab1,fab2 but not working for fab_open, fab_close ...

Comment: Those are animations not a view element. So it seems your implementations was correct for animation initialize. You just have to bind animations to view elements and start.

Comment: thank you :) , but instead of getContext() you should put getActivity() , I tried it and it works